# Dafny: Postcondition error in constructor

Tags: dafny

The following constructor does not work and fails at

**parent !in Repr**

Why can't Dafny proof the postcondition, that parent is not part of the Repr set?

```
constructor Init(x: HashObj, parent:Node?)
    ensures Valid() && fresh(Repr - {this, data})
    ensures Contents == {x.get_hash()}
    ensures Repr == {this, data};
    ensures left == null;
    ensures right == null;
    ensures data == x;
    ensures parent != null ==> parent !in Repr;
    ensures this in Repr;
{
    data := x;
    left := null;
    right := null;
    Contents := {x.get_hash()};
    Repr := {this} + {data};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `HashObj` is a `trait`? (If it's a `class`, then your example verifies for me.) The verification fails because the verifier thinks `x` might equal `parent`.

The verifier ought to know that `Node` is not a `HashObj` (unless, of course, your class `Node` really does extend `HashObj`), but it doesn't. You may file this as an Issue on https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny to get that corrected.

In the meantime, you can write a precondition that says `x` and `parent` are different. Here, there's a wrinkle, too. You'd like to write

```
requires x != parent
```

but (unless `Node` really does extend `HashObj`) this does not type check. So, you would want to cast `parent` to `object?`. There's no direct syntax for such an up-cast, but you can do it with a let expression:

```
requires x != var o: object? := parent; o
```

Comment: Thank you! HashObj is a trait, but Node does not extend this or any other trait.

Comment: It solved the problem in this method but caused additional problems in other code locations. Thus I have selected a different approach.